# How can separate Modules, each with distinct Derived-Types and associated procedures, USE each other?

Tags: fortran, derived-types

The free-form program's modules employ a hierarchy beginning with Global_Module. Global is then USEd by both Channel_Module and Mode_Module and that works just fine. All Modules employ `IMPLICIT NONE`.
I've isolated the below compiler error to the `USE Channel_Module` statement within the Modes Type's associated initialization procedure within Modes_Module.

I'm sure that DT's are intended to share data with one another thru associated procedures but for unknown reason it's not working in this case. Both Global and Channel compile with 0 errors and warnings. Both Channel and Modes previously accessed data from their Global parent just fine. Everything is Public. However, I now need these two siblings to access select components across module boundaries by passing as TYPE or CLASS to no avail. I've tried limiting the `USE` to `ONLY` the Channel's DT but that had no effect on the compile outcome. I'm wondering if I'm missing something about How to do this.
How is Derived-Type cross-referencing intended to be accomplished in this scenario?

> Compiling with Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler XE 12.0.4.196
>   [IA-32]... ifort /nologo /debug:full /Od /fpscomp:filesfromcmd
>   /warn:declarations /warn:unused /warn:truncated_source
>   /warn:interfaces /module:"Debug\" /object:"Debug\"
>   /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /traceback /check:bounds /libs:static /threads
>   /dbglibs /c /Qvc9 /Qlocation,link,"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin" "C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\ELA\ELA\Modes_Mdl.f90"

I think the following Pseudo-code should help to clarify this issue. Channel is init'd first, followed by Modes. After successful Modes init, Channel%myArray is then intended to be populated via Channel%calculatemyArray.

In file Channel_mdl.f90:

```
MODULE Channel_MODULE
   USE GLOBAL_MODULE !omitted for clarity
   TYPE Channel_TYPE
      ! some vars
      REAL, DIMENSION(3,12) :: myArray
      LOGICAL :: populated = .false. !set to true in initChannel_Type
      CONTAINS
         PROCEDURE :: initialize => initChannel_Type !omitted for clarity
         PROCEDURE :: calculatemyArray !to be Called following successful init of Modes, thus need to share info between these objects.
   END TYPE Channel_TYPE
CONTAINS
   LOGICAL FUNCTION calculatemyArray(this, Mds) !populate myArray
      USE Modes_Module !need access to Modes%Qty array
      IMPLICIT NONE
      CLASS(Channel_Type), INTENT(INOUT) :: this
      TYPE (Mode_Type), INTENT(IN) :: Mds
      calculatemyArray = .true. !unless error occurs herein
!     initialization process ...
   END FUNCTION calculatemyArray
END MODULE Channel_Module
```

In file Modes_Mdl.f90

```
MODULE Modes_MODULE
   USE GLOBAL_MODULE !omitted for clarity
   TYPE Modes_TYPE
      ! some vars
      INT(int16), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: Qty
      LOGICAL :: populated = .false.
      CONTAINS
         PROCEDURE :: initialize => initializeModes
   END TYPE Modes_TYPE
CONTAINS
   SUBROUTINE initializeModes(this, Srcs)
      USE Channel_Module !need access to Srcs%Count to allocate Qty array
      IMPLICIT NONE
      CLASS(Modes_Type), INTENT(INOUT) :: this
      TYPE (Channel_Type), INTENT(IN) :: Srcs
!     initialization process ...
      ALLOCATE(Qty(Srcs%Count))
      populated = .true.
   END SUBROUTINE initializeModes
END MODULE Modes_Module
```

In file myPgm.f90

```
Program foo
   USE Channel_Module
   USE Modes_Module
   IMPLICIT NONE
   TYPE (Channel_Type) :: Channels
   TYPE (Mode_Type) :: Modes
   Call Channels%initialize()
   IF (Channels%populated) THEN
      Call Modes%initialize(Channels)
!  other statements & functions
   END IF
END Program foo
```

Ya know what's both sad and good at the same time? Discovering that what I wanted was preventing me from getting what I needed. In the above scenario, I think the whole problem goes away if I pass only the Channel's Count sub-component value (an INT) rather than the whole Channel object (that which I thought I wanted).
I'd still very much like to know the How to go about passing DT objects between DT procedures however. The means to do so seems elusive...

Comment: You can't have cyclic dependencies (if that's the requirement), but for us to say more sensibly you should show code of (or at least close to) what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: So, how does Type_B's associated procedure access data from Type_A if it can't USE a dummy argument to reference it?

Comment: see comment from @francescalus, show some code / pseudo code.

Comment: Citing my answer in [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969831/2938526) question: "You have to design your solution wisely. Separate your modules by subject and dependency. If three types reference each other then they are very related should be in the same program unit."

Comment: Oh, that's right! I do recall reading that DTs defined within the same module can talk to one another or something close to that effect. Alright, the mental model of how these meld together is starting to gel.

Comment: The not-passed arguments to the type bound procedures (`Mds` and `Srcs`) are not polymorphic, which implies that you don't intend having a type hierarchy based on either of those types and will not be overriding the bindings.  Is that the case?

Comment: Wow, too many negative inferences for me to interpret your intent correctly, i.e., not-passed, not polymorphic, don't, will not all in one sentence makes my head spin.

Comment: Let me put it a different way - why do your types have type bound procedures?

Comment: Trying to work within the Fortran OOP framework. Type-bound procedures seems like a good idea, especially for initialization. The objects, Channels and Modes, are referenced as Class objects within those procedures. Admittedly, I'm climbing the learning curve. I envision being able to Add and Delete other objects (via pointers) to/from these objects and construct a cohesive, system data model. Having them as separate Modules within separate files isn't strictly necessary but does help with human maintenance.

Comment: Isn't it not an option to just pass Modes%Qty and Srcs%Count as actual arguments to the type-bound procedures directly? (in other words, define the latter procedures using primitive data types rather than derived types except for the 1st argument (= "this"))

Comment: You are correct, @roygvib. In developing the pseudo-code I discovered my folly and concluded precisely what you suggest. I was over-zealous in passing more than was needed. One could say that I erroneously wanted all of "this", not just a piece of it!
See bottom of my OP.

Comment: Another approach may be to have two or multiple types (e.g. A_t and B_t) into a single module by including "A_type.f90", "B_type.f90", "A_procs.f90", "B_procs.f90" etc (each containing type and procedure definitions). This allows mutual reference of different types, but the files are separated. I use this approach for some part of my programs, but I guess it is usually more recommended to make type or module coupling as weak as possible... e.g. [coupling (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)))